# Is it a bad practice to write multiline commit messages on git?

Tags: git, version-control, git-commit, conventions, commit-message

My commit messages on git usually look like the following:

```
* Fix bug abc
* Refactor xyz
* Document 123
* ...
```

I'm wondering whether this is a bad practice and I should prefer one-line commit messages or at least provide a header line.

On the other hand, this would be less comfortable to write ...

What are your recommendations?

Comment: Here is what Linus Torvalds (the creator of git) [thinks a good commit message looks like](https://github.com/torvalds/subsurface-for-dirk/blob/a48494d2fbed58c751e9b7e8fbff88582f9b2d02/README#L88)

Comment: The separation of a single line as subject, followed by a blank line and then a description, if necessary, is widely considered good practice. In addition to the link @CupofJava provided [this post](https://chris.beams.io/posts/git-commit/) is a good guideline.

Comment: In many repository viewers (for example, `gitk`) this will show the commit as `* Fix bug abc`. Decide for yourself if this is desirable. But: Considering this example, there really should be three commits, not one.

Comment: Thanks for the note! Is there also any rational (technological) reason for leaving empty lines and so on instead of using bullet star points?

Comment: it depends greatly on how your team wants to work, and how the people can see the commit messages. Also, most project management tools (Jira, Trello, Azure DevOps, Tuleap, etc...) provide a way to link the commit message with the actual commit by indicating your "ticket/item/artifact/Product backlog item/task" like this @1234

Answer (score 12):

Git standard (even though you can do as you please) is:

- single line with a brief summary of the change
- empty line
- All the gory details in multiple lines

Comment: I never noticed about this empty line recommandation but you're right. I guess it's more or less impactful depending on your habits and workflow, but good to enforce anyway.

Comment: For context, empty line convention comes from git itself. For example git commit -m "foo" -m "bar" will result in 3 lines.